# I'm looking for a better way to structure Apollo Client Queries when building a table with tabs

Tags: reactjs, apollo-client, react-apollo

I am building a page in React using Apollo Client to make GQL requests to the backend (that I'm also making). I frequently use this pattern for rendering data in tables where I have one query that gets only the Id's of the rows I want to render. I then loop over each Id and give that to a 'Row' to render by making a gql request for it's data. I like this pattern because it allows me to nest tables of data inside the table with no additional tweaking.

[Example table with arrows to show or hide more information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gpk5m.png)

```js
export default function ExTable(){
    // Get just the ids of the rows that should be rendered
    const { data } = useGetTableDataIds()

    const rows = data.queryData ?? []

    return (
        <table>
            {
                rows.map(r=><TableRow key={`row-${r}`} id={r}/>)
            }
        </table>
    )
}

function TableRow({id}:{id:number}){
    // Load data for provided id
    const { data } = useGetRowData({variables: {id}})

    // Render row using data ...
    return <tr/>
}
```

What I don't like about this is all of the requests for data are made individually. I would prefer  one request for all of the data. The thing I don't like is that if this data request lives at the top of the table it might be more difficult to prevent the whole table from re-rendering.

Are there any best practices on requesting data that may be frequently mutated for tables? What about when that data has a lot of optionally loaded nested data inside of it?